# Could anyone confirm if I correctly understand how plugging a gap in someone's national insurance record works? (mixing Class 2 and Class 3 NICs)

Tags: united-kingdom, national-insurance

Assume that a person became self-employed part of the way through the 2015-2016 tax year and subsequently paid voluntary Class 2 national insurance for 21 weeks.

If they now send the NI office a cheque for £437.10 for Class 3 contributions to cover the additional 31 weeks*, would this mean they get an additional qualifying year for the state pension?

Thanks for any replies!

*calculated as 31 weeks at £14.10 (using the appropriate rate for that tax year, and not the current rate of 14.25):
https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/rates-and-allowances-national-insurance-contributions/rates-and-allowances-national-insurance-contributions

Comment: What was the status before the self-employment? Employed, or not? Also have the person looked at their NI record online, I think that explicitly says what you would need to pay?

Comment: They were unemployed but not claiming benefits.  They have tried to access their NI record online but it wasn't working, and they keep getting redirected to the self-assessment page.  They could send a request for a written record, but that takes a while to come back.